# Limiting MapQuest place-search to one country

Tags: javascript, mapquest

Using MapQuest place-search.js I'm trying to set a 'circle' using coordinates and a radius to limit the returned results roughly to my country.

I read the documentation at https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/search-api/v4/swagger/ and then wrote this code, but mapquest seems to completely ignore the circle option and still shows cities from all over the world.

```
placeSearch({
        key: 'MY_MAPQUEST_KEY',
        collection: ['adminArea'],
        circle:[52.21158, 5.600489,200000],
        sort:'relevance',
        container: document.querySelector('#place-search-input')
    }).on('change', (e) => {
        $('#location').val(e.result.city);
    });
```

How do I limit the search to only my country (the Netherlands), or at least relevant places in or very close to my country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Place Search api is currently available for the US and Canada. Other areas should be available within the next year or so.

Comment: I ended up coding my own version using Twitter Typeahead and the MapQuest search / prediction api